# What is the right/preferred name for a data structure akin to JavaScript objects in Java or any other language?

Tags: javascript, java, php, json

I have been reminded several times (and now remind SO users myself) that JSON is a text encoding, and is different from JavaScript Objects.

In PHP, you can work with arrays in much the same way as in JavaScript. In J2EE you can create a JsonArray or a JsonStructure (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html)... In reference to these Java objects, to me this already seem like a bastardization of what JSON was created to mean.

So my question: What is the correct way to describe a JSON-like data structure in a language other than JavaScript? Is there anything better than JSON? If I said to my colleague asking about the contents of an Array in my PHP page, is it wrong to say "It is a JSON"? The alternative I guess is associative array (or map) but an associative array is much broader than a JavaScript object, which again can only contain arrays, objects, and key-value pairs.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but since JSON exists outside of the languages that use it, it is called for what it is, JSON, nothing more and nothing less, similar to XML.

Comment: You're right, Hover.  JSON is simply an encoding scheme, like XML or YAML, and it happens to be the one which is most commonly used e.g. with AJAX calls.  You take a data-structure and turn it into a corresponding JSON string or vice-versa.  *Back in far more innocent days,* the format "really *was* JavaScript," and you simply dealt with it by `exec()` on the string!  But now it has become a standard format like the others, with equally *standardized* support for it in most every language.  (All of whom generally use the same libraries to do the heavy lifting.)

Comment: "If I said to my colleague asking about the contents of an Array in my PHP page, is it wrong to say "It is a JSON"" ...yes, if it's actually a PHP array. JSON is a text-based format used for transmitting and storing data. Once you've decoded that data string into a variable in your chosen language, it's no longer JSON.

Comment: "In J2EE you can create a JsonArray or a JsonStructure"...these are just convenience classes meant for the _creation_ and/or _reading_ of JSON data in a generic way (without de(serialising) to/from a more concrete type). Other languages have libraries containing similar classes (e.g. JObject and JArray in the Newtonsoft.JSON library for .NET). They're meant for working with JSON, it's not saying that those classes _are_ JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy with Hovercraft Full of Eels answer. While "JSON" might not have been intended to be used for this purpose, it is the best way to describe this kind of data structure.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is an encoded representation of your data structures in PHP or whatever language you choose to use.

This process can be referred to by many names, [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), [marshalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) to name a few.

Comment: Hi Rattybag you have missed the core of my question (maybe it wasn't as clear as it could be). I understand that JSON was developed initially for serializing JavaScript Objects and Arrays. But my question was about what to call a in memory non-serialized data structure that works the same way as JavaScripts Objects and Arrays *outside of JavaScript*